# Keyboard is Auto-correcting my capitalization in Word, Browser, and Windows Explorer.

Tags: windows-7, wireless-keyboard

I have a Microsoft Wireless Comfort Keyboard 1.0A Model 1027 for a Windows 7 system.  Somehow it is Auto-correcting my capitalization in Word, my Browser, and Windows Explorer.  In Word: Office Button>Word Options>Proofing>Auto Correct Options...>"Auto Correct" tab, none of the auto correct boxes for Capitalization mistakes are checked.
If I try to type something like USDA, it might come out as USDa.  I believe I remember that it can also come out as Usda, or USda, but am not 100% sure.  It seems to be somewhat random and intermittent; it sometimes will do what I want.
After a while, this behavior is incredibly annoying.  I very much want to see exactly what I am typing and don't want to be second guessed about it.
How can this be corrected?
Thank-you for your time.

Comment: check your accessibility options (Ease of Access), look especially at sticky keys.

Comment: I'd have suspicions about your shift key being broken. Does it do this on any other keyboards?

Answer (score 0):

Yes!  it only took me a year and a half to get this figured out.
I had failed to mention in my initial complaint that most of the "Shortcut" buttons worked either, where they had before.
This is for anyone else who has this or a similar problem with Microsoft Wireless Comfort Keyboard.  Here's the poop.
It's not the Keyboard, it's the Driver.
Microsoft Mouse & Keyboard Center does not "support" Microsoft Wireless Comfort Keyboard.

Navigate to this page...
http://www.tacktech.com/news.cfm?nid=32762

You will see that there are several versions of Intellitype.  When you select the version you want in the lower part of the window, it appears in the upper part and the appropriate download can then be selected (32bit, 64bit, etc).

Uninstall "Microsoft Mouse & Keyboard Center" using Control Panel/Programs & Features.

Install Intellitype.

Note that some versions may not work.  For example, in my case, I started with v8.2, thinking newer is better.  heh...  Not.  After uninstalling that, I installed v7.0, which works flawlessly.

It appears that somehow, "Microsoft Mouse & Keyboard Center" managed to install itself on my machine, overwriting IntelliType.  I dunno.  But, if I ever have a problem again, I know what to do.  And now, so do you.